# Keep the data in UITextFields as it is even after the navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield

I made an app with multiple `UITextFields` in FirstView for the Registration purpose.

I kept modify account feature in app. For the purpose of modify account I need to navigate the user into registration page. But whatever the data entered by the user in fields such as `Name, Date of Birth, Mobile Number` etc is not appearing there after the navigation.I need to keep the data as it is in `UITextFields`.This is the first time am facing this issue.help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance for everyone

Comment: Is your view controller in navigation stack only when you navigate to the other view?

Comment: i could not understand ur comment

Comment: Are you pushing the other view controller from one which has text fields?

Comment: When you push to the FirstView, all the textfields are cleared. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: not other viewcontroller that is the firstview for registration. i need to take him back to the first view only

Comment: yes, exactly  @Suresh

Comment: can you explore some of your code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create & push to a ViewController, all the data in that ViewController will be cleared. You have to pass the new values to that ViewController and you have to re-assign the values after pushed.

```
FirstView *first = [[FirstView alloc] init];
first.name = @"My Name";
first.age = @20;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:first animated:YES];
```

.h file

```
@interface FirstView : UIViewController{
    UITextField *nameField;
    UITextField *ageField;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *age;

@end
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    nameField.text = self.name;
    ageField.text = self.age;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to store the UITextField values in NSUserDefaults.  This will store the values and you'll be able to access them again (and from anywhere in your code actually).

Say your UITextField is named ageTextField you could do this to store the text:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ageTextField.text forKey:@"age"];
```

To get the values back into your UITextField you could do this in viewWillAppear (just in case it never left memory)

```
ageTextField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"age"];
```

Just a side note.  I typically make those NSUserDefaults keys constants (ie kAge) so you don't mistype them and have access to them else where.

Comment: i tried this one but with NSUserDefaults i can't able to use the data in same viewcontroller

Comment: Sorry I should have told you to add this line after setting the object:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];